# File Data is blank array in server side: Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to post File using JQuery. Below is my code.

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#frmUpdateProfile').on("submit", function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation(); // Stop stuff happening
            event.preventDefault(); // Totally stop stuff happening
            var data = {
                "FileName"      :   event.target.FileName.files,
                "_token"        :   "{!! csrf_token() !!}"
            };
            $.ajax({
                url:            '{{URL::route("UpdateProfile")}}',
                method:         "POST",
                async:          true,
                data:           JSON.stringify(data),
                processData:    false,
                contentType:    "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (msg) {
                    SuccessCallback(msg);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR) {
                    ErrorCallback(jqXHR);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I tried `processData: false,`. While debugging in Js, you can check that image is coming in the data. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

But when I print the request data in Laravel, it show blank array.

**Html form is here**

```
<form method="POST" 
        action="http://localhost:1234/AS6-Code/public/UpdateProfile" 
        accept-charset="UTF-8" 
        enctype="multipart/form-data"  
        id="frmUpdateProfile">

    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="26KWkWdNqe5iOFE8VRBf1dRnL5xKxwN25jg3tAFW">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="26KWkWdNqe5iOFE8VRBf1dRnL5xKxwN25jg3tAFW">
    <input multiple="1" name="FileName" type="file">
    <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending your request with [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) instead:

```
var data = new FormData($('#frmUpdateProfile')[0]);
```

Also set contentType to false:

```
contentType: false
```

Also Update

```
event.target.FileName.files
```

to

```
event.target.FileName.files[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

`event.target.FileName.files` is a FileList object. I believe you need `event.target.FileName.files[0]` instead.